# Remove all web url's from a string using VB.net and RegEx

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

I'd like a function (in VB.net) that is passed a string, and then removes any web addresses from that string using a regular expression. It needs to be able to handle url's in different formats, e.g.:

```
http://www.mysite.com
https://www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com
http://mysite.co.uk/mypage.htm
```

It should also strip out any anchor tags containing web url's.

Basically, it should not expect url's to be prefixed with `http` (or `https`) and neither should it expect there to be a `www.` or `.com`.

The function then returns the original string, albeit with any web addresses removed.

So far, all I've been able to come up with is the following (though this doesn't cater for urls contained within anchor tags), and I noticed that if I put 2 urls seperated by only a space, it leaves one of them.

```
<Extension()> _
    Public Function ReplaceWebUrls(ByVal s As String) As String
        s = " " + s + " "

        s = Regex.Replace(s, "([\s])(www\..*?|http://.*?)([\s])", " ")
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "([\s])(https://.*?)([\s])", " ")

        Return s.Trim()
    End Function
```

VB.net is not something I normally use, but on this occasion I have no choice, and regular expressions are not my strong point :(

Comment: So what does it do with “this.url”? Or “localhost/test”? Both can be valid URIs. In fact, I have set up my local server to have “phd” as a valid URI for presentations.

Comment: I don't need to handle internal/local urls. Just try to handle the majority of mainstream, common structured type of addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S*
```

or

```
(?:(?<=\s)|^)(?:https?://|www\.)\S*
```

and replace each match with empty string.